# How to return only first match result in XPath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I tried to use XPath `string-after` to grab data after Property ID: but the result is not what I want.It show all the result that matched with Property ID. I want only `P-000324`.  And here are my code

```
<?php
$getURL = file_get_contents('http://realestate.com.kh/residential-for-rent-in-phnom-penh-daun-penh-phsar-chas-2-beds-apartment-1001192296/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($getURL);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

echo $xpath->evaluate("normalize-space(substring-after(., 'Property ID:'))");
```

So how can I make it get **only one first result**?

Comment: What's your expected result? `Property ID: P-000324`?

Comment: I want result to be like this P-000324

Comment: Oh, then you need to do a substring-before also to prune out rest of the line.  I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33656346/290085) to do that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your XPath expression to select the string after **only the first occurrence** of a `p` that contains `Property ID:` by using a position index (`[1]`).

For example, the following XPath expression will select just the first paragraph that directly contains the string 'Property ID:':

```
(//p[contains(text(),'Property ID:')])[1]
```

Putting this together with your request to return just the string that follows 'Property ID:' but nothing beyond the `P-000324` string:

```
echo $xpath->evaluate("normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after((//p[contains(text(),'Property ID:')])[1], 'Property ID:'), '–'))");
```

will echo just `P-000324` as requested.

**Update**: This solves the problem for the original page as it was originally presented, but the goal seems to be broader per the comments.  A more robust solution would be to use just the first expression to obtain the string for the first paragraph containing 'Property ID' and then do regex pattern matching immediately after the label on normal forms of the property id or normal forms of delimiters surrounding property id.  You'll have to use the regex facilities of the hosting language as XPath 1.0's string processing functions are very limited; XPath 2.0's are much better and included regex capabilities.

Comment: But it still have another result

Comment: No, look again carefully.  It only returns "*P-000324 – Location: Phsar Chas...*" for your example page.

Comment: I want result to be like this P-000324

Comment: No problem.  Answer updated to return just "P-000324".

Comment: kjhughes now it worked! but you know when i test another url it not work. Can u please check it? this url: http://realestate.com.kh/residential-for-sale-in-koh-kong-kaoh-kong-ta-tai-kraom-2-beds-apartment-1001192243/

Comment: @lyju the markup is inconsistent. These property descriptions are presumably created in a WYSIWYG editor and therefore you can't guarantee the format. Retrieving the property ID in this manner consistently seems an unlikely feat

Comment: @BenSwinburne is correct.  In this second case, There's a space and a separate tag surrounding the `:` after "Property ID".  The id that follows also doesn't precede a `-`.   You're asking a new question, really, now.  If you want to make the most general solution given these sorts of variations, you probably should use XPath 1.0 to locate the entire first string as I've shown, but then use PHP's regex pattern matching to find the first numeric string following the "Property ID" substring.  That will be more robust, but as Ben points out, still not guaranteed to be perfect.

Comment: @kjhughes please help me to do that; I spent a whole day but cannot solve this.